# How to get posts by meta value as multi-dimensional array?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, array

I know how to get posts by a specific post meta when the meta value is a string.

```
$meta_query = [
    [
        'key' => $meta_key,
        'value' => $meta_value,
        'compare' => '='
    ]
];            
$res_query = new \WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'order_by' => 'ID',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'posts_per_page'=> '-1'
   )
);
$posts = $res_query->posts;
```

But when `$meta_value` is an multi-dimensionnal array like :

```
$post_meta = [
    'my_plugin_values' => [
         'key_1' => 'value 1',
         'key_2' => 'value 2'
     ]
]
```

And I want to get posts which have `$post_meta['my_plugin_values']['key_2'] === 'X'`,
How can I do this ?
Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: You can't. Meta cannot be stored as a multidimensional array. When stored it's stored as a serialised string and then unserialised when loaded. So you can only query it as a string. If you need to perform a query like this then you should store `key_1` and `key_2` as separate post meta keys, rather than as part of an array.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie, thanks for your answer. I found a work around : in `$meta_query['value']`, you serialize all the multidimensionnal array. So, you need to know all the values inside the array. That works. I will do the answer.